# Parsing a string in C# using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

I have string of a particular type
**(A, B) C | D  0,  7 | E  0,  6 | F  0,  6**
where A, B, C, D, E and F are known but the numbers has to be extracted.

Is there a way by which this can be done using Regex or something else in C#?

Comment: Have you tried named groups ? http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's always the format of the string you'd be parsing, you could just use a simple String.Split:

```
var elements = yourString.Split(new[] {'(', ')', '|', ',', ' '},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then just use `elements[0]` to get the value represented by `A`, etc. and cast it back to an integer or whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: This is one option even I thought of.
I was thinking if its possible with regex